# Where is the Rust u128 overflow happening?

Tags: rust, overflow

I am attempting Leetcode 43. During the test runs, my total variable goes negative
(a bit odd for a u128 I would have thought!). Can anyone tell me where I am going
wrong. I tried porting the code into Python which ran fine (but slow).

```
pub fn multiply(num1: String, num2: String) -> String {
    let mut dec_counter: u128 = 0;
    let mut total: u128 = 0;

    for dec in (0..num1.len()).rev() {
        let outer_dig = (num1.as_bytes()[dec] - '0' as u8) as u128;
        let mut unit_counter: u128 = 0;
        for i in (0..num2.len()).rev() {
            let digit1: u128 = (num2.as_bytes()[i] - '0' as u8) as u128;
            total = total
                + (outer_dig
                    * digit1
                    * 10u128.pow(unit_counter as u32)
                    * 10u128.pow(dec_counter as u32));
            println!("total is: {}", total);
            unit_counter += 1;
        }
        dec_counter += 1;
    }

    total.to_string()
}
```

Comment: A `u128` can only store numbers with at most `log10(2^128) ~= 38` decimal digits. If your input is larger, then you may want to consider using a different representation to store `total`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I see you are right. The test case does cause the total to exceed 38 digits hence my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: And the reason it works fine in Python is that in that particular language, if the need arises, it seamlessly and behind the scenes switches to a "BigInt" representation.